# 10,000 + records on html to render quickly

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, render

Now this is going to be a very absurd question. But what can I do, it's the client's requirement. Basically, we have a grid (master-detail type) that goes up to about 15 thousand plus rows (has the potential to go up to 30-50 thousand rows in a few years time).

My client does NOT want any paging, does not want any data cropped as well. Also he isn't exactly using the latest hardware so rendering on browsers is a big issue. He wants to view everything by printing it out or looking through it on the browser. (You may all think how insane that sounds, and it sure is).

Now I want to resolve this issue by rendering html quickly. At the moment its a simple asp.net grid view w/o paging. That essentially renders HTML tables. My options that I think are: 
 - Manually rendering html using div (for quick loading)
 - export it to pdf or excel (is there any way to export without the need to resort to third party controls?)
 - give the finger (to the client :D j/k)

So to sum up, whats the best way to show 10,000 plus records of data on html?

Comment: you do have options, use Nustache to render objects to html and then append to a container, use YUI Data table and lastly can you client side code to use Backbone.js to delegate a progressive loading type table which will load more rows as you scroll or hit load more button

Comment: Long *tables* can be slow as (older) browsers need to read the whole table before they can start laying out the page. Maybe a non-table solution would work better.

Comment: You would have to consider if whatever solution you offer you client would be happy with the result, I would be more inclined to mock up a demo using generic UI controls and let the client see just what sort of poor user experience he should expect otherwise your reputation could suffer which is not worth it for unrealistic expectations.

Comment: @deeptechtons: Many thanks for your suggestion. Am trying that out, templates certainly helps out, however on the progressive loading issue, just a bit uneasy on that as it some times fails.

Comment: @Hans Kesting: you are right, long table have that issue on page rendering, am considering using divs as the alternative, however since the data is a grid form (typical row/cell type), creating div just takes a bit longer, havent run the performance tests on both yet so not sure how much benefit would be gained by using divs..

Comment: @Lloyd: if only our client would understand, we've tried exactly what you say, they just dont seem to understand it. They are the typical 'one-click-do-everything- type of client.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

consider using the "Scroller" [plug-in for Datatables](http://datatables.net/blog/Introducing_Scroller_-_Virtual_Scrolling_for_DataTables)..

> As part of DataTables 1.8 release a new plug-in called "Scroller" was
>   introduced as part of the download package. Scroller is an
>   implementation of virtual scrolling for DataTables, which presents a
>   vertically scrolling table, scrolling the full height of the table,
>   but drawing only the rows which are necessary for the visible display,
>   leading to a huge performance increase. This is quite an exciting
>   plug-in for DataTables not only for the performance increase, but also
>   because it effectively provide a new user interaction with the table,
>   allowing full scrolling of very large data sets.

Comment: Thanks for that mate :) looking into that now. Cheers

Answer (score 3):

I know this is almost a year late, but in case it helps someone.

Use [SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid) - It uses divs instead of tables, which gives so much more performance in IE. Check this [example](http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example12-fillbrowser.html)

Answer (score 2):

You should do the paging - it does not mean that you need to show only one page of data at a time but rather you should retrieve and render pageful of data at a time (and keep continuously fetching pages one after one till data is finished).

For example, send the first page of data from the server in the initial request. Setup a js timer and use AJAX requests to retrieve subsequent pages of data and load that into the browser. You can have multiple (say 3-4) AJAX requests going on simultaneously for retrieving pages - only thing would be to achieve the ordering correctly in such approach.

I will personally avoid grid-view and render the html table using manual java-script (with help for jquery) or use some java-script template engine. I will use JSON for retrieving the data from the server.

Comment: He said he can't implement paging due client requirements.

Comment: @BojanSkrchevski, client wants to view all data together and not a pageful at a time. Please read the answer carefully - I am advising paging for retrieving & showing the data i.e. you keep loading the pageful of data using timer.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, VinnaC. :) Progressing loading is definatly the way forward here, however I havent play much with it before, and it seemed to have issues at times with different browsers, and since our client's machines are ancient with stone age browsers, you never know when AJAX and javascript just give up.

Answer (score 2):

> He wants to view everything by printing

This is imho the only viable solution to view all information. PDF or Excel is ***much*** better at handling a large number of rows.

Doing the rendering is quite easy. Just set the excel mime type and return a HTML table.

http://www.designdetector.com/archives/05/07/HTMLToExcelTheEasyWay.php

When it comes to PDF, you probably have to use an external library like PDFSharp.

Comment: Cheers jgauffin. :) i've been looking into pdfsharp and other open source pdf generators. Didn't realise for simple table structure, switching the mime type opens it up in excel. Thanks for that :)